# Install Jenkins before version 2.235.3

Tags: jenkins

As you may know the GPG key for jenkins after version 2.235.3 is changed.

> https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/27/repository-signing-keys-changing/

Now I am setting the key as follow and for version after 2.235.3, i am able to install successfully

> https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key

While for some reason, I also need the old version of jenkins.
For my case, 2.164.1-1.1
But I am getting this error.
Are there another key for old version?

```
STDOUT: Public key for jenkins-2.164.1-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed

STDERR: warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/2/jenkins-ci/packages/jenkins-2.164.1-1.1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID d50582e6: NOKEY
Importing GPG key 0x45F2C3D5:
 Userid     : "Jenkins Project <jenkinsci-board@googlegroups.com>"
 Fingerprint: 62a9 756b fd78 0c37 7cf2 4ba8 fcef 32e7 45f2 c3d5
 From       : https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key


Public key for jenkins-2.164.1-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed


 Failing package is: jenkins-2.164.1-1.1.noarch
 GPG Keys are configured as: https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the key as follow to install the version before 2.235.3

> https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key